# stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource seems kind of permanent

Tags: ios

I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController, then startAccessingSecurityScopedResource, doing stuff, working fine and then stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource. So far so good. But I pass some of the info to another method and it then needs to call startAccessingSecurityScopedResource. However, that fails every time. What worked the first time fails every time afterwards. It is as if a start-stop sequence renders the NSURL permanently (for the current run) inaccessible. Is this the intended design? Is there a workaround?

```
BOOL accessingSecurityScopedURL = [urls[0] startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

[fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL: urls[0]
                                    options: NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges
                                      error: &error
                                 byAccessor: ^( NSURL* newURL ){

    BOOL    isDir = YES;
    BOOL    exists = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath: newURL.path isDirectory: &isDir ];
    // . . . 
}];

if ( accessingSecurityScopedURL )
    [urls[0] stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

// . . .
// This will now fail:
accessingSecurityScopedURL = [urls[0] startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```

Comment: Yup, don't call stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource unless you are certain you don't need access to that resource anymore